# count_alpha in c languahe, a programme that counts occurances of letters in a string and prints the letter next to its count number

Tags: c, string, count, printf, find-occurrences

can someone advise how can I print the repeating letter with its final count/occurance once? I have the following code and after it the output but I want the output to be: 2a, 1b, 3c instead of 1a, 2a, 1b, 1c, 2c, 3c

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int str_len(char *str)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(str[i])
    i++;
    return(i);
}

void count_alpha(char *str)
{
    int tab[26] = {0};
    int i = 0;
    int len = str_len(str);
    while(str[i])
    {
        if (str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z')
        {
            if(tab[str[i] - 'a'] == 0)
                tab[str[i] - 'a'] = 1;
            else
            tab[str[i] - 'a']++;
    
        } 
        if(tab[str[i] - 'a'] < len)
        printf("%d%c, ", tab[str[i] - 'a'], str[i]);    
        i++;
}
}

int main()
{   
    char str[] = "aabccc";
    count_alpha(str);
    return(0);
}
```

output

1a, 2a, 1b, 1c, 2c, 3c, %

i need a simple way to write the letter just once with its final occurrence count

Answer (score 0):

Move this part:

```
if(tab[str[i] - 'a'] < len)
  printf("%d%c, ", tab[str[i] - 'a'], str[i]);
```

Out of the while loop and into a for loop of its own:

```
 for(i=0; i<26; i++)
 {
   if(tab[i] > 0)
     printf("%d%c, ", tab[str[i] - 'a'], str[i]);    
 }
```

Misc other problems:

- Use const correctness. `void count_alpha(char *str)` -> `void count_alpha(const char *str)`.
- Arithmetic on symbol values such as `str[i] - 'a'` is strictly speaking not well-defined and isn't guaranteed to work (except for the symbols `'0'` to `'9'`). For a fully portable and strictly conforming program, you would instead do `int tab[256] = {0};` and then access it with an index corresponding to the symbol value. (Would also make the algorithm case-sensitive and faster, at the expense of stack memory use.)
- This part here is nonsense, just remove it since it fills no purpose:

  ```c
  if(tab[str[i] - 'a'] == 0)
    tab[str[i] - 'a'] = 1;
  else
  ```
- Making your own function `str_len` instead of calling standard `strlen` just makes your program much slower for no good reason.
- `return(i);` The parenthesis around the return value is pointless.

Comment: @MSU `if(i != 25) printf(", ");`

Comment: thank you @Lundin that's very helpful
i added another loop and it works perfectly 
`
i = 0; 
 while(str[i])
 { 
  if(tab[str[i] - 'a'] != 0)
  printf("%d%c, ", tab[str[i] - 'a'], str[i]);
  
  tab[str[i] - 'a'] = 0;
  i++;
 }


--
so the out put to this:

int main()
{ 
 char str[] = "aaabcc";
 count_alpha(str);
 return(0);
}
`
--
output 
--
3a, 1b, 2c,

now only problem I don't want the last comma to appear
I want it as 
3a, 1b, 2c

Comment: in this case it would print as below 
`3a, , , 1b, 2c, ,`

the code is 

`i = 0; 
 while(str[i])
 { 
  if(tab[str[i] - 'a'] != 0)
  printf("%d%c", tab[str[i] - 'a'], str[i]);
  if (i < 25)
  printf(", ");
  tab[str[i] - 'a'] = 0;
  i++;
 }`

Comment: @MSU Did you even read this answer? Move the printing out of the while loop.